# Moving the placement a div in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css

I have a function that I built (it's kind of bare bones at the moment), but I can't find how to move the object when it expands onMouseOver so it doesn't move the others on the page, is this possible?

```
function expandbox(x) {
    x.style.height = "100px";
    x.style.width = "100px";
}

function returnbox(x) {
    x.style.height = "80px";
    x.style.width = "80px";
}
```

Comment: To prevent it from moving the other elements, set its position to absolute, and then assign a z-index.

Answer (score 1):

Make the element position relative inside a relative  container, then change it's dimensions.

Make sure to give it higher z-index.
Place it with `left,right,top,bottom` properties of `style`.

Comment: It doesn't need to be *inside* a relative container, it just needs to be `position: relative` itself.

Comment: @xec, You might want to [read this](http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/).

Comment: But we're not trying to move an **absolutely** positioned element, we're trying to move a **relatively** positioned element.

Comment: @xec,true, though usually when you need z-index, you want `position:absolute`, not relative.

Comment: Then why do you suggest to use position relative in your answer :(

Comment: @xec, the container... the container... I think it's easy to understand.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28304/discussion-between-xec-and-gdoron)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the element in document flow, set it to `position: relative` and move it around using `top` and `left`, which will be relative to where the element started out.

I'll use the same type of function you made, to demonstrate:

```
function moveBox(x) {
    x.style.position = "relative";
    // move 20px down and 10px left from original position
    x.style.top = "20px";
    x.style.left = "-10px";
}
```

If you want to remove the box from document flow (following elements will not be affected by its presence) set its position to `absolute` instead. Top and left values will be relative to its **closest positioned ancestor** (or `<body>` if there is none, as i assume in the comment below)

```
function moveBox(x) {
    x.style.position = "absolute";
    // position box 20px from top of body
    x.style.top = "20px";
    // and 10px from the left
    x.style.left = "10px";
}
```

An element is considered to be "positioned"  if it has a value other than `static` (default, [read more here](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-css3-positioning-20120207/#positioned)), so if you want to control what the absolutely positioned element is relative to, you can give a container element `position: relative`